# Android Listview with spinner and radio button

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom array adapter which implements list-view with spinner and radio button in each row in a list. When selecting radio button, each lists radio button gets selected. How to get selected with single choice list row.

How to select only single list using radio button.

Sorry for bad english.

Here is the code.

getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_list_row, null);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.data = new DataModel(myContext);
        viewHolder.spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());
        viewHolder.radioBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice);
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setTag(position);
        //viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(selectedPos == position);

        viewHolder.spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                viewHolder.data.setSelected(arg2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

        viewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                selectedPos = (Integer)view.getTag();
            }
        });

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        view = convertView;
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.spin.setSelection(getItem(position).getSelected());
    holder.radioBtn.setChecked(selectedPos == position);
    return view;
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search list.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#f8f8ff"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:textFilterEnabled="true"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

single_row_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/options"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_prompt" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checked="false"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    DataModel data = new DataModel(this);
    DataModel data1 = new DataModel(this);
    DataModel data2 = new DataModel(this);
    DataModel data3 = new DataModel(this);
    DataModel data4 = new DataModel(this);

    d = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.single_list_row, new DataModel[] { data, data1, data2, data3, data4 });
    lv.setAdapter(d);
}
```

DataModel Class

```
 public class DataModel { 

    private int selected; 
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter; 

    public DataModel(Context parent){ 
           adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(parent, R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
           sadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     }

    public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> getAdapter() { return adapter; } 

    public int getSelected() { return selected; } 

    public void setSelected(int selected) { this.selected = selected; }
}
```

Complete Adapter Class:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel>
{
private Activity myContext;
int selectedPos = 0;
int flag = 0;
int pos = 0;

public ListAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, DataModel[] objects)
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    myContext = context;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    protected DataModel data;
    protected Spinner spin;
    protected RadioButton radioBtn;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_list_row, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.data = new DataModel(myContext);

        viewHolder.spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());
        viewHolder.radioBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice);
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setTag(position);

        if(selectedPos == position)
        {
            viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    //viewHolder.data = new DataModel(myContext);
    //viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());

    viewHolder.spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            viewHolder.data.setSelected(arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });

    viewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            selectedPos = (Integer)view.getTag();
        }
    });

    viewHolder.spin.setSelection(getItem(position).getSelected());
    viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(selectedPos == position);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: can you follow my answer and see how that goes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_list_row, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.data = new DataModel(myContext);

        viewHolder.selectedText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singleitem);
        viewHolder.spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());
        viewHolder.radioBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            viewHolder.data.setSelected(arg2);
            viewHolder.selectedText.setText(viewHolder.data.getText());
            //Log.v("", String.valueOf(viewHolder.spin.getSelectedItemPosition()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
        {
        }
    });

    if(flag != 1)
    {
        if (selectedPos == position)
        {
            viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
    }

    viewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(flag != 1)
            {
                if (((RadioButton) view).isChecked())
                {
                    selectedPos = position;
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedPos = -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ((RadioButton) view).setChecked(true);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    //viewHolder.spin.setSelection(getItem(position).getSelected());
    viewHolder.selectedText.setText(viewHolder.data.getText());
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

`RadioButtons` are considered as active elements,

Can you add,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

and add,

```
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to your RadioButton Element otherwise you will not get those click events.

I see some issue in your code, Try this out

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator = myContext.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.single_list_row, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.spin = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        viewHolder.radioBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.choice);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


        viewHolder.data = new DataModel(myContext);
        viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());
        viewHolder.radioBtn.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                viewHolder.data.setSelected(arg2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

        viewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                selectedPos = (Integer)view.getTag();
            }
        });


    viewHolder.spin.setSelection(getItem(position).getSelected());
    viewHolder.radioBtn.setChecked(selectedPos == position);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
    return view;
}
```

The issue is in this code,

```
viewHolder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                selectedPos = (Integer)view.getTag();
            }
        });
```

this `(Integer)view.getTag()` is giving the position, So all the time the if statement is true.

I suggest you to Maintain the selected state form a boolean value in DataModel and use it to maintain the selected radio buttons.

Please post the complete adapter class to see what you are doing there.

Comment: @Kruise Sorry for the mistake, Can you check now

Comment: viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter());

Comment: viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(viewHolder.data.getAdapter()); Sir, i am getting null pointer exception here

Comment: public class DataModel
{
private int selected;
private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
public DataModel(Context parent){
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(parent, R.array.options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> getAdapter()
    {
        return adapter;
    }

    public int getSelected()
    {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(int selected)
    {
        this.selected = selected;
    }}

Comment: Sir, still all radio button is getting selected.

Comment: Sir, when debbuged both selectedPos and position values are same.